# Can I exclude the timing of 1 method of the PurePath

Tags: dynatrace

We have a fat-client frontend where we created a custom method on "button clicks". This works and gives us complete traces from click until backend. sofar so good...

Issue is that sometimes, the gui logic determines that a dialog needs to be opened to ask the user either for confirmation or for additional info.
Here comes the issue: When an end user waits for a minute before answering the question in the dialog (also a custom method defined in Dynatrace), the duration of the complete purepath is procesingtime+1minute.

There is a naming rule that splits the requests of the "button clicks custom method", based on some functional information, so there are about 40 button-click request types. (this is somewhat dynamic).

This is a traditional dynatrace-SaaS environment, so I don't have GRAIL options yet...

Is there a way to get a listing showing either both values (total processing time + Dialog open time) or a net-processing time (total-dialog)?

I tried to get this information in data explorer (only key requests splitable for my service), not possible to get both "total processing" and "dialog subnode" timing in 1 query.